# Cost and Usage Reports vs aws cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

What is the difference between Cost and Usage Reports and aws cost explorer? We can see graph in aws cost explorer and also we can see graph of Cost and Usage Reports in Amazon QuickSight. Where is the difference between Cost and Usage Reports and cost explorer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not difference. Cost explorer is just a fancy wrapper over cost and usage reports.

Comment: It is good to include AWS Budget in the comparison study

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question, we better describe each at their basic usage first.

So what is **AWS Cost Explorer**?

> AWS Cost Explorer is a tool that enables you to view and analyze your costs and usage. You can explore your usage and costs using the main graph, the Cost Explorer cost and usage reports, or the Cost Explorer RI reports. You can view data for up to the last 12 months ...

As you can see, there are a few things that you can see from the official documentation.

- A tool
- Explore usage up to the last 12 months

From above points, we can clearly understand that it is a **built-in** tool that AWS has given us for daily usage without having to deploy any details dashboard.

Then, what is **Cost & Usage Report (CUR)**?

> The AWS Cost and Usage Reports (AWS CUR) contains the most comprehensive set of cost and usage data available. You can use Cost and Usage Reports to publish your AWS billing reports to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket that you own.

As you can see, we can see some good points here:

- Usage raw data
- Publish raw data to your own storage such as Amazon S3 bucket

From above points, we can notice **CUR** provides us advantages against **Cost Explorer**.

- What if your boss want to know your AWS cost from 2 years ago?
- What if your boss want to view your AWS cost from PowerBI/Tableau/QuickSight? (Of course, usually your boss does not want to log in to an AWS account which is not familiar with him/her)

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-what-is.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html